# standard evaluation in dplyr: "could not find function" error for functions in global environment

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use standard evaluation in dplyr with functions in the global environment but I get the "could not find function" error. Here is some code

```
# create data.frame
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
# define arbitrary function
test <- function(x) x^2
# use standard evaluation with dplyr
df %>% mutate_("mean(x)")
df %>% mutate_("test(x)")
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : could not find function "test"
```

I can circumvent this problem by using `df %>% mutate_(~test(x))` but I would like to use the string-based approach for various reasons. The main reason is that the user can pass a vector of variable names `x` to my function. I can use this vector to apply the same transformation to all variables by passing something like this `as.list(sprintf('mean(%s, na.rm=TRUE)', x))` to `.dots`. Here is the full code

```
x <- c('x','y')
df %>% mutate_(.dots=as.list(sprintf('mean(%s, na.rm=TRUE)', x)))
df %>% mutate_(.dots=as.list(sprintf('test(%s, na.rm=TRUE)', x)))
```

So my questions is why the string-based approach does not work with functions in the global environment? What can I do to make it work? Or is it possible to adopt the formula-based approach so that it works with vectors of variable names?

#### sessionInfo() output

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] magrittr_1.5            dplyr_0.3.0.2           plyr_1.8.1              maptools_0.8-30         sp_1.0-16               Rcpp_0.11.3            
 [7] matrixStats_0.10.0      rgeos_0.3-8             stringr_0.6.2           mvtnorm_1.0-0           RcppArmadillo_0.4.400.0 Defaults_1.1-1         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1    DBI_0.3.1         foreign_0.8-61    grid_3.1.1        lattice_0.20-29   lazyeval_0.1.9    parallel_3.1.1    R.methodsS3_1.6.1
[9] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: This is well explained in the `vignette("nse")`: *`It’s best to use a formula, because a formula captures both the expression to evaluate, and the environment in which it should be a evaluated. This is important if the expression is a mixture of variables in the data frame and objects in the local environment:`* And it goes on with an example and a comment *`# Using anything other than a formula will fail because it doesn't know which environment to look in`*

Comment: ANd of course you could turn your string into a formula with `as.formula(paste0("~", "test(x)"))` such that `df %>% mutate_(as.formula(paste0("~", "test(x)")))` would work.

Comment: Is there something different in our setups? I'm running dply_0.3.0.2 and I get errors with both `df %>% mutate_(as.formula(paste0("~", "test(x)")))` and `df %>% mutate(~test(x))`: `"Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: @BondedDust You are using dplyr's mutate and not plyr's, right? That error message seems to imply that the data.frame isn't being passed in as the first parameter, or maybe you haven't defined a `df` data.frame and it's using the default stats `df()` function? (One reason why I don't like using `df` for a data.frame name.)

Comment: MrFlick's approach works for me but I have to add an `llply` call to make it work for a vector of variable names: `dots <- as.list(sprintf('~test(%s)', x)); df %>% mutate_(.dots=llply(dots, as.formula))`

Comment: @MrFlick: My understanding was that one should NOT use plyr with dplyr and since this was supposedly a question about dplyr, I assumed that `dplyr::mutate_` was the function under scrutiny. But you were right about why the error message was so inscutable. I had left off the "d" in the "df" dataframe name.

Comment: @BondedDust That's what I assumed as well. I was just guessing that might cause your error.

Comment: @BondedDust: I think MrFlick just suggested possibilities why the code might not run for you. His solution is entirely `dplyr` based. My addition for variable vectors adds an `plyr::llply` call though. You can use both packages but you should load `plyr` first.

Comment: So I concluded that you really wanted a method for accepting user input and checking it before passing to `dplyr::mutate_` in an acceptable manner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using standard evaluation with a udf in dplyr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634744/using-standard-evaluation-with-a-udf-in-dplyr)