# Using standard evaluation with a udf in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am programming with dplyr and therefore I am using standard evaluation. I make a generic function with a data frame and a column name as arguments. Within the function I would like to apply another function that I wrote myself on the column of the data frame. Here is a minimal example:

```
some_udf <- function(x) mean(x + 3)
generic_function <- function(dat, input_var){
  dat %>% dplyr::summarise_(mean_3 = sprintf("some_udf(%s)", input_var))
}
```

Now when running the generic function I'll get the following error:

```
generic_function(mtcars, 'cyl')

Error: could not find function "some_udf"
```

When `some_udf` is replaced by a base R function, like `mean` or `sd`, all works fine.

Could someone explain to me why the udf is not working in this case and what a solution might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787116/standard-evaluation-in-dplyr-could-not-find-function-error-for-functions-in-g), which doesn't have an accepted answer, but as pointed out in the comments by David Arenburg and MrFlick, you need to pass the expression as a formula so that the correct environment context is available:

```
library(dplyr)

some_udf <- function(x) mean(x + 3)
generic_function <- function(dat, input_var){
    dat %>% 
        summarise_(mean_3 = as.formula(sprintf("~some_udf(%s)", input_var)))
}

generic_function(mtcars, 'cyl')
#   mean_3
# 1 9.1875
```

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate, thanks for pointing it out. I will remove this post.

Comment: @Edwin No you should actually keep this post. Since the other question does not have any answers, it cannot be referenced as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok then I won't :)

Answer (score 2):

Read the [`nse` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) and use the recommended `interp` method:

```
generic_function <- function(dat, input_var){
  dat %>% 
    dplyr::summarise_(mean_3 = lazyeval::interp(~some_udf(x), x = as.name(input_var)))
}

generic_function(mtcars, 'cyl')
```

> ```
>   mean_3
> 1 9.1875
> ```